# Append scraped data to different columns

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
while True:
        for rate in soup.find_all('div',{"class":"rating"}):
         if rate.img is not None:   
               print (rate.img['alt'])
        try:
            driver.find_element_by_link_text('Next').click()
        except:
            break

driver.quit()
```

```
while True:
         for rate in soup.findAll('div',{"class":"listing_title"}):
            print (rate.a.text)
         try:
             driver.find_element_by_link_text('Next').click()
         except:
             break

driver.quit()
```

Comment: It is against the [terms of service](http://www.tripadvisor.com/pages/terms.html) of TripAdvisor to scrape the site. Please don't do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you're looking for. You should grab the parent class of both (I chose `.listing`, and get each attribute from there, insert them in a dict, and then write the dicts to CSV with the Python CSV library. Just as a fair warning, I didn't run it until it broke, I just broke after the second loop to save some computing.

## WARNING HAVE NOT TESTED ON FULL SITE

```
import csv
import time

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'http://www.tripadvisor.in/Hotels-g186338-London_England-Hotels.html'

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

hotels = []

while True:
    html = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    listings = soup.select('div.listing')

    for l in listings:
        hotel = {}
        hotel['name'] =  l.select('a.property_title')[0].text
        hotel['rating'] = float(l.select('img.sprite-ratings')[0]['alt'].split('of')[0])
        hotels.append(hotel)

    next = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Next')
    if not next:
        break
    else:
        next.click()
        time.sleep(0.5)

if len(hotels) > 0:
    with open('ratings.csv', 'w') as f:
        fieldnames = [ k for k in hotels[0].keys() ]
        writer = csv.DictWriter(f,fieldnames=fieldnames)
        writer.writeheader()
        for h in hotels:
            writer.writerow(h)

driver.quit()
```

Comment: Please do not deface your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at using a [list](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-list).

I would try something like this:

```
for rate in soup.findAll('div',{"class":["rating","listing_title"]}):
```

(could be wrong, this machine doesn't have bs4 for me to check, sorry)